# Brownie / Rinkeby: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, brownie

I was following the tutorial from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=16103s) and now I'm stuck during **deploying a contract to rinkeby testnet**.

If I run `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby` I get an error:

```sh
BrownieProject is an active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "brownie/network/web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File "brownie/network/web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

I checked the `brownie-config.yaml` file and .env for typing errors but haven't found anything.

brownie-config.yaml

```yaml
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

I already created an infura api and add it in the .env file as `export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=abc12345656789`.

If I run the command `brownie run scripts/deploy.py` everything works fine so I can exclude any typo. Does someone have an idea what's the problem?

I use Brownie v1.17.2

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are not loading environment variable in your file. install `python-dotenv`

```
  pip install python-dotenv
```

In your `deploy.py` if .env is in the same directory:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv 

#default directory for .env file is the current directory
#if you set .env in different directory, put the directory address load_dotenv("directory_of_.env)
load_dotenv()
```

then use it like this:

```
 private_key=os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working :( if I do `source .env` and echo the variable nothing is shown.. (I use conda as virtual env)

Comment: @VicWild why are u doing `source .env`

Comment: Using `load_env()` works for me but I also want to try loading them by `brownie-config.yaml` and its not working

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this means your environment variables are not set correctly, and it looks like in this case it's your `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID`.

You can fix it by setting the variable in your `.env` file and adding `dotenv: .env` to your `brownie-config.yaml`.

`brownie-config.yaml`:

```
dotenv: .env
```

`.env`:

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE
```

Remember to save these files.

Additionally, you should be on at least brownie version v1.14.6. You can find out what version you're on with:

```
brownie --version
```

---

If you know how to [set environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) you might want to check if you're setting them correctly.

Comment: I'm on Windows and these steps are not working for me. It works using `load_env()` but not using brownie-config.yaml. any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, my config file was not in project root.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure you set the .env correctly you can try sourcing your .env file in the terminal:

```
source .env
```

and then try running your script again.